# Setting up TwitterBootstrap with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

This is what I have done so far:

1) create new ASP.NET MVC 4 project in VS2012.

2) select the "internet application" template (which includes membership and entity framework)

3) test it, it works fine

4) using the package manager, run:

```
> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4
> Install-Package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample
```

5) in "_ViewStart.cshtml", change

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
```

to

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml"
```

Unfortunately, when I run it now, I get the following error:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml": "featured".
```

I'm new to ASP.NET and am not really sure what's going on and why this is happening. Any ideas?

As a second question, once I get this fixed, how can I install a template from http://wrapbootstrap.com? I can't seem to find any instructions for how to do it with ASP.NET.

Comment: You should make your second question exactly that...another question. The simple answer to it is you can't just drop it in because it's designed to work with bootstrap not ASP MVC. You need to do a bunch of work to make those templates work. Ask the question as a new question and you might get some better advice.

Comment: A general suggestion: you might find useful a library [TwitterBootstrapMvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your Home/index.cshtml there are sections defined that aren't in the bootstrap layout.

either add them to the new layout (see Shared/_Layout.cshtml for how, you're looking for something called featured) or delete them from the index.cshtml.

For homework look up how to define sections in ASP.MVC

Comment: I had to change \Views\Home\Inbox.cshtml and comment @section featured block

Comment: The bootstrap "out of the box" solution needs to be more of an "out of the box" solution, obviously understanding sections is helpful, but fixing code that should work shouldn't require doing homework

Comment: hanzolo see BillH's answer for the kind of solution you are after. See my answer for why it was breaking and do the homework on how to use sections in ASP.MVC to understand the error being thrown. Mine is a complete and accurate answer that addresses the question and doesn't demand that the world should be a certain way.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably too late for the original poster, but I think a better solution is to start with an Empty MVC 4 project.  That way, you don't have to delete anything.

```
1) Start with an empty ASP.NET MVC 4 project.
2) Using the package manager, run:

    install-package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4
    install-package twitter.bootstrap.mvc4.sample
```

This builds and runs fine on my VS2012.

It seems to me that this was the original way the sample code was intended to be installed.

Answer (score 4):

In the **_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml** verify that you have "featured" in the @RenderSection :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="@Styles.Url("~/content/css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
    @Html.Partial("_html5shiv")
</head>
```